# Handling of SVGs between Blender 2.7x and Blender 2.8x

Tags: mesh, extrude, svg

Below is an image of an imported SVG (of course it's the same SVG for both versions of Blender!) notice that 2.79b does a much nicer job of "extruding" the 2D shape and filling.

In both cases, extrusion depth is set to 0.0001m and no other settings are changed.

[image]

Now, let's see Blender's 2.8x handling of the SVG:

[image]

Really ugly! What's causing this difference? I can turn the Resolution Preview U in 2.8x down which makes the SVG look a little nicer.

In 2.8, the import initially looks like this in 2D:

[image]

Why can 2.7x do something better than 2.8x can?!

I'm initially creating my SVGs by generating a PDF with LaTeX and then using pdftocairo to convert the PDF to an SVG.

Comment: Try changing/increasing the Preview resolution U.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger yes, decreasing the preview resolution to around 5 makes the object look nice again, as I wrote. However, increasing it makes it look horrible and 2.7x is only set to 12... I have a lot of SVGs and I don't particularly want to change U for all of them.

Comment: What is the number of (Lot of SVGs)? Your comment is revealing something that can be in the original question. (Lot of SVGs ... rather than a few).  Such info can be put in your original statement. If your objects can be selected or put in a collection you may be able to change all the values at one via the GUI.  If you are adequately versed in Python and Blender you may write a script.

Comment: You may want have an additional question.  How do I change some value for all the selected items?

Comment: How does the render look as opposed to the preview?

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger unsure what the number of SVGs has to do with anything? Let's say, more than 20. I'm just curious why this happens in 2.8 and not 2.7...

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger the preview shown in 2.8 is with rendered viewport. In 2.7, the render looks very smooth, as it does in "solid" view.

Comment: Just dropped some cursive letters from Inkscape into Blender 2.82, I don't see any issue. Could you please provide the svg used in your question ?

Comment: @thibsert is an Dropbox link OK? I'm using 2.82.7. The SVG imports fine on 2.79b, so I'm not sure if it's an SVG issue. https://www.dropbox.com/s/3fxf06hdf0nbbyb/text_for_slm_image.svg?dl=0

Comment: If you give yout text a more useable size (like x10) then Apply Scale, the problem disappears. I guess it has to do with how 2.8x handles (or approximate) really small numeric values (some points of your curve are distant by a few micrometers!)

Comment: @thibsert thanks! Applying scale fixed it. If you want to leave a quick answer I'd be happy to set it as correct. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give yout text a more usable size (like x10) then Apply Scale, the problem disappears.

Looks like 2.8 viewport is less precise than 2.7 on really small numbers, probably for optimization purposes.